# Export Laravel excel Image failed

Tags: php, excel, laravel, phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

Dotrying to export my daanswerdata through laravel excel. https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/- this is the documentation I used for reference. At first, it is running successfully, but when I open the exported file, it exports the path of the image instead of exporting the actual images. Is there a way to export the image(the png file)?

This is exported file
[image: exported file]

this is the local path folder where the image saved
[image: local path]

this is how its look like in my database [image: db structure] .

here is my code:

1.Export.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\signature;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

//frow laravel excel  drawing(image export) 
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnWidths;





class SignatureExport implements FromCollection,  WithHeadings, WithColumnWidths
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return signature::all();
    }


    public function drawings()
    {
    

        $drawing = new Drawing();

    
        $drawing->setName('signature');
        $drawing->setDescription('This is my signatuer');
        $drawing->setPath(public_path('/uploads/signatures'));
        
        $drawing->setHeight(90);
        $drawing->setCoordinates('D1');

        return $drawing;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'signature',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
        ];
    }

    public function columnWidths(): array
{
    return [
        'A' => 30,
        'B' => 30,        
        'C' => 30,
        'D' => 30,    
        'E' => 30,          
    ];
}


}
```

2.Export Controller

```
   public function exportexcel()
    {

        return Excel::download(new SignatureExport, 'signaturelist.xlsx');

    }
```

Do I miss anything? any answer is appreciated.

---

problem solved with the answers that are being accepted .
but ther is new problem came out

instead of 3 image , only 1 image exported sucessfully
[image: only 1]

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\signature;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

//frow laravel excel  drawing(image export) 
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithDrawings;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnWidths;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting;






class SignatureExport implements FromCollection,  WithHeadings, WithColumnWidths, WithDrawings
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return signature::all();
    }


    public function drawings()
    {
    

        $drawing = new Drawing();

        $drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
        $drawing->setName('signature');
        $drawing->setDescription('This is my signatuer');
        $drawing->setPath(public_path('/uploads/signatures/62ac8a575af1a.png'));
        
        $drawing->setHeight(90);
        $drawing->setCoordinates('D1');

        return $drawing;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'signature',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
        ];
    }

    public function columnWidths(): array
{
    return [
        'A' => 30,
        'B' => 30,        
        'C' => 30,
        'D' => 30,    
        'E' => 30,          
    ];
}


}
```

what should i do to get all image being exported?

Comment: you have not implemented the WithDrawings concern. [Drawings | Laravel Exports](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/drawings.html#adding-a-single-drawing)

Comment: I think have called the use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing;   and there is a function of for drawings on controller ? isnt that enough? what do i miss .@AnujShrestha
'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SignatureExport class file you are missing the `WithDrawings` implements

```
class SignatureExport implements WithDrawings //like this
```

So your `SignatureExport` class should look something like this

```
class SignatureExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithColumnWidths, WithDrawings
```

`use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing;`

This import is just to instance   `$drawing = new Drawing();` object.
For the export file to work you will need to add `withDrawing` concerns like you are adding `WithHeadings` and others

Comment: Glad to be of help :). Also, please accept this as an answer so the question can be closed :)

Comment: yes I have already accepted the answer, but there is another problem that came out, can you help me?  Right now only one image has been exported instead of 3 .. i will update my questions

Comment: in your code, you are setting the image for only 1 Excel Cell D1 so the image is drawn only in that cell only you will have to loop the drawing process and increase the coordinate accordingly

Comment: ok noted. i will try it again when i have time . Thanks again for your help